# Change the path of JS and CSS in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to change the path of my Angular website, from `http://localhost:4200/` to `http://localhost:4200/something/`

I have modified `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "something/login", component: MyLoginComponent },
  { path: "", redirectTo: "something", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "something", redirectTo: "something/login", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "**", component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];`
```

All is working fine in `http://localhost:4200/something`, except the following paths:

```
http://localhost:4200/runtime.js
http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js
http://localhost:4200/vendor.js
http://localhost:4200/main.js
http://localhost:4200/styles.js
http://localhost:4200/styles.css
```

I want all of them in `http://localhost:4200/something`

Please, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is not how Angular works. What you do is to set the `Router`. The router has nothing to do with the path of any file like "main.js" or "polyfills.js". That are files created by Angular. All inside the main (dist) folder. And the routes otherwise are **URLs** so to say.

If your problem is the start location, so named `base href` you can set this inside the index.html

```
<head>
  <base href="/something/">
</head>
```

or with help of Angulars CLI on building:

```
ng build --base-href /something/
```

All other things, so *where* the created files will be stored, is not our part. It is alone Angulars thing!

Comment: Thank you Flo! I have tried this, but then I get 404 errors, for example http://localhost:4200/something/main.js get 404. 
How Can I solve this? Sorry I'm new in angular. 
Thank you for advance!

Comment: What do you want to do with main.js? Its enough to call localhost:4200/something. This index.html includes the main.js.

Comment: If I have the path localhost:4200, the website is working fine. But if change to localhost:4200/something, the page is blank and I get these errors:

login:16     GET http://localhost:4200/something/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
login:16 GET http://localhost:4200/something/polyfills.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
login:16          GET http://localhost:4200/something/vendor.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
login:16 GET http://localhost:4200/something/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
login:16 GET http://localhost:4200/something/styles.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: The "base href" is only important is your websites url www.mysite.de (as example) and your workdir is something. So: "www.mysite.de/something". But in development you don't need "base href". All should work fine with localhost:4200. If nothing will work create a simple Stackblitz example and I will look to it.

Comment: Yes, I do this because I want to put this website in kubernetes in the path www.mysite.de/something. I said to kubernets that all of /something redirect to my website. All is working but the page is blank because for example www.mysite.de/something/runtime.js get 404.

Comment: I'm not good in K8s. So I hope anyone else can help you. Sorry.

Comment: Hi Flo. I have resolved the problem, I put  "baseHref": "/something/" in /projects/my-project/architect/build/options of angular.json file. Now all is working fine except assets, they are remaining in / instead of /something. Do you know how I can change them